# How to set default index to launch first.html but allow root / to still work?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have to set a temporary html splash page, but ensure all links remain the same.

Hence the root / still launches the Wordpress home page but the fist page shown when users hit the site will be first.html

Can anyone provide ways of doing this via htaccess or any other way?

The site is running in an Apache environment with CPanel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in your .htaccess to set the default index page

```
DirectoryIndex first.html
```

But then how are you going to get to your wordpress  site after that shows? You'd have to use some type of Javascript redirect or meta refresh and modify your .htaccess rules. *If* I was going to do something like this, I'd use a plugin that is designed to have a splash screen and then show the site. There seems to be several usable ones.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=splash

Comment: The problem is we are trying to avoid using Wordpress for this - otherwise it would be easy since I could adjust which page is the front page. The reason is we have a massive hit to the server coming, hence have to suppport a heavy load so we want a flat html page toavoid any DB calls etc.. The only way I can think might work is setting the wordpress site to work from /index.php and ensuring any internal links to root reference index.php instead. Just wondering if there is a better way via the Unix server setup

Comment: Ok, I figured it out - you were half way there. I'll post a full answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out, so in case this helps anyone else...

I added this to my .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex first.html index.html index.php
```

Then in my functions.php file I added the line:

```
remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

The above line allows the Wordpress front page to run from /index.php
If this line is missing then the index.php page keeps redirecting back to / and displaying first.html

Now the home page and site can stay where it was without modifying any configuration settings and the permalinks can remain unchanged.

When we no longer want the first.html to display, we remove the line in the htaccess and the filter call.